# How to get top 100 objects only from a JavaScript filter method

Tags: javascript, arrays

For showing autocomplete I need top 100 objects that satisfy the filter condition from an array of 100k objects, the operation should not proceed once I get 100 records
I don't need the whole list of objects to be filtered

```
filter() {

    if (this.DataArray != null && this.AutoCompleteText != null)
        this.filteredList = this.DataArray.filter(function(el) {
            return el.value.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.AutoCompleteText.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        }
            .bind(this));
}
```

Comment: `.slice(0, 100)`?

Comment: slice will reduce the data source thats not what i wanted, i want the result set to contain 100 matching records

Comment: Use a `for()` loop   and break when you push enough into new array

Comment: btw, you could use `thisArg` for `this` without binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and count the filtered items. When `count` is zero, then the loop ends.

```
filter() {
    var count = 100;
    if (this.DataArray != null && this.AutoCompleteText != null) {
        this.filteredList = [];
        this.DataArray.some(function(el) {
            if (el.value.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.AutoCompleteText.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                this.filteredList.push(el);
                return !--count;
            }                
        }, this);
    }
}
```